Visual Studio Code and Azure Functions keeps running old code locally (MacOS, Node.js)
In the array "users" there are almost thousand entities. I run code locally (Run and debug) and canceled it at some point. If I try to run again even commented code:
var tasks = [];
for (const userEmail of users) {
    var task = context.df.callSubOrchestrator('MainMailingSendToUserOrchestrator', { userEmail });
    tasks.push(task);
}
yield context.df.Task.all(tasks);

then the suborchestrators keeps going, no matter what code I have inside the function.
How to clean cache or fix that?
launch.json:
{
   "name": "Mailing",
   "type": "node",
   "request": "attach",
   "port": 9230,
   "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
}


Check below steps to clear cache of durable functions in Visual Studio Code:
Add the command json "command": "${command:workbench.action.clearEditorHistory}" in tasks.json. Thanks @Ishtiaque Khan for the commands.
.vscode/tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "label": "func: host start",
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-node-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": "npm install (functions)"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "npm install (functions)",
            "command": "npm install"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "npm prune (functions)",
            "command": "npm prune --production",
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "clear-editor-history",
      "command": "${command:workbench.action.clearEditorHistory}"
        }
    ]
}

launch.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
        ...
            "preLaunchTask": "clear-editor-history"
        ...
        }
    ]
}

Or you can clear the cache with below steps:

Open command palette in Visual Studio Code(Cmd  +  Shift  +  P)
Type command Clear Search History=>Enter
Type command Clear Editor History=> Enter


The local Azurite storage emulator may have old entries of the orchestrator and activity functions, clear the cache of the Azure Storage Emulator.
Search for Azurite:Clean in command palette=>Enter.

Restart VS Code to apply the changes after clearing the cache.
Refer article for other ways to clear cache.
When working with multiple test runs, old orchestration history can cause confusions. If the previous orchestrations are still in progress or have left some residual state, purging the history will remove it and allows to start fresh.
Purge the orchestration state using Azure Core Tools command func durable purge-history, refer SO.

Thank you for your answer. I cannot clean table service in vscode using Azurite Clean Table Service:
"Clean Azurite Table Service error: Cannot clean LokiTableMetadataStore, it's not closed." I cant find how to close it.

Run Azurite:Close

@MR, Is the issue resolved?

not exactly. I still got "Cannot clean LokiTableMetadataStore, it's not closed." Azurite: Close not helped. I switched my account and use other git credentials in vscode and after that problem disappeared. Maybe it was coincedence and suborchaestrators just expired? I really don't know. Are they expiring?

func durable purge-history throws alert: Could not find DurableTask.AzureStorage.dll. The functions host must be running a Durable Functions app in order for Durable Functions CLI commands to work.
So I guess it works only on windows.
